# How to change the prompt in Linux?

Tags: bash, prompt

The default prompt will be

```
root@monu dev]#
```

Can we change the "root@monu" part and give it a desired name?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is changed by changing the environment variable `PS1`.

You can see the current value of `PS1` by:

```
root@monu dev# echo $PS1
```

You can see the value to be equal to `\u@\h \w\$`, where:

- `\u` : username
- `\h` : hostname
- `\w` : current working directory
- `\$` : a `#` symbol for the root user, a `$` symbol for other users

If you want the change to be permanent, you have to add the script changing the value of `PS1` in `~/.bashrc`, since that it gets executed every time a user logs in.

Comment: Don't forget to put it into your ~/.bashrc file also. e.g. `PS1="myname \\$ "'.

Comment: ~/.bashrc is _not_ executed every time a user logs in. “When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.” – man bash /INVOCATION

Comment: *By changing them, you can change.*?

Comment: For details, see the `PROMPTING` section with `man bash`.

Comment: Yes, but how exactly? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Note: Was having trouble with $ not turning to #.  Apparently in solaris /etc/profile PS1 UID marker must be escaped twice:  \\$

Answer (score 5):

This depends on your shell.  *As an important side note, you should **never** use the root account as a personal account.  Create a normal user and set up access to sudo.  Please check your distribution manual as to how to do this.*

In zsh, you need to set the PROMPT variable like so:

```
PROMPT='%{ESC[38;5;24m%};%{ESC[0m%} '
```

zshell offers a lot of [other](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/) [options](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/) and this is really a minimal prompt.

In bash, you can set it this way:

```
local ROOK="\[\033[38;5;24m\]"
local DEFAULT="\[\033[0;39m\]"
PS1="${ROOK}\$${DEFAULT} "
```

Note that in both cases, I have a 256 colour enabled terminal.  The man page will help a lot (`man bash` or `man zsh`).

Comment: Here, you stated the *root account* case correctly, IMO - it is not to be used *as a personal account* (except on some very low-footprint embedded systems).